# How do I include a term's additional fields on node display?

Tags: entities, taxonomy-terms

With Drupal 6 there was Taxonomy Image to do this, but with the field goodness of Drupal 7 we can just add an imagefield to a certain vocabulary. This works quite well to output stuff with views, but I can't seem to find a way to show up the additional field on the node display.

In my case I simply have a vocabulary called countries that has an additional imagefield to hold the country's flag. When viewing a node that has assigned a country term I need the flag of the country to show up instead of its name.

Regards,
Daniel

Comment: How are you structuring your output? Are you using any modified templates? or just the node's view as configured through the Drupal UI?

Comment: Lately I'm trying to avoid specific node templates as far as possible and use [Semantic Fields](http://drupal.org/project/semantic_fields) instead.

Comment: I have no idea about Semantic Fields but this is generally very possible using stock display settings of the node. You should make use of a [Entity Refence](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) field while attaching the taxonomy to your content type. You should then choose 'Rendered entity' for that taxonomy field and go with it. You can create as many view modes as you want with [Entity View modes](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_view_mode). And you can manage display of the vocabulary for that view mode as you desire.

Answer (score -1):

I've not played with semantic fields before, but I can tell you that configuring a term's display is the same as configuring a nodes display. The administration for a vocabularies display can be found at Structure --> Taxonomy --> VOCAB_NAME --> Manage Display or the path

```
admin/structure/taxonomy/VOCAB_NAME/display
```

Again, same as nodes you can configure the labeling & formatting options from this area. However, the location to configure a node's display is Structure --> Content Types --> YOUR_TYPE --> Manage Display

These settings are used for Drupal's native output. Using views can bypass these settings depending on the view (fields) or can work together (full, default, teaser).

Comment: Thanks, but configuring a vocab's display is only relevant for showing term overviews, such as countries/austria and on the node display settings the only options for displaying a term refernce field are "Link", "Plain text" and "RSS Category", none of them outputs a term's additional field.

Comment: So your goal is to display, a term's image field when viewing a node that term is attached to? I may have misunderstood what you were after.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Well, now I got it, I was probably reading too fast. I'll update my answer